# Is overriding JavaFx TreeItem getChildren add a good idea?

Tags: javafx, treeview, overriding

My aim is to have a process done during all addition to children in a Tree (a TableTreeView to be precise).

The `node.getTreeItem().getChildren.add(playlist)` is called in different parts of my code, and I tried to keep best practices as much as possible... so let's keep it simple and say I will for sure call it while a drag'n'drop is done, as well as at the building of the tree.

My 'playlist' can be of 3 different types (in enum class) :

- FOLDER (containing other playlist)
- LIST (containing tracks added by user)
- QUERY (containing tracks as result of a query)
- MISTAKE (should never be set, but useful for debug and so)

I want to implement a method on my 'extended' `TreeItem<Playlist>` such as `getPlaylistType()`.
This method would return the type of the playlist.

QUESTION :
My instinct would say I should Override the `node.getTreeItem().getChildren.add(playlist)` to set the type in a way :

- There are children playlist --> FOLDER
- No children playlist && query exists --> QUERY
- No children playlist && query does not exists --> LIST
- Any other state --> UNKOWN/MISTAKE

1. Is this approach correct ?
2. How to Override the 'add(...)' method ?

Comment: At the moment, I use a method in my `TreeItemPlaylist` class: `public boolean addToChildren(TreeItemPlaylist playlist) {...}` which holds the `getChildren.add(playlist)` and any additional processing I need. Probably not the most elegant... For example this does not prevent bypassing my customized process after adding the node when `node.getTreeItem().getChildren.add(playlist)` is used.

Comment: _My instinct would say I should Override the node.getTreeItem().getChildren.add(playlist)_ with all due respect: don't listen to the instinct, it's wrong ;) BTW: don't add details to a question in comments, instead edit the question to include them.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expose `node.getTreeItem().getChildren.add(playlist)` to different parts of your software? If you just wrap it in your own class you could expose that and do whatever you want when the corresponding `add` method is called.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer ! I do have my own extended `TreeItemPlaylist extends TreeItem<TreeTableRowPlaylist>` class... I have not overridden `getChildren()`, (an `ObservableList<TreeItem<TreeTableRowPlaylist>>`), and thus also not the `add(...)` (`java.util.List.add(TreeItem<TreeTableRowPlaylist> e)`). Should I ? If so, how ?

Comment: you can make an add(...) method in your "extended" class, do your check and call getChildren().add(...) from there, and replace calls to getChildren().add(...) with calls to your add(...) method in your extended class, although the default getChildren() will still be exposed to different parts of your software as @mipa have said, you can wrap a TreeItem<Playlist> attribute in your class instead of overriding it and only expose the methods that need to be exposed.

Comment: What I meant was wrapping up the whole thing and only expose that. That would be cleaner and would be hiding your implementation details.

Comment: So, if I'm reading your solution correctly, @mipa, this is what I have suggested as temporary solution in my question comment. Yes ? Still feels uncomfortable to have the `getChildren.add(playlist)`